# Explanation and idiomatic solution(s) for assignments to arrays in classes in F#

Tags: f#

I've been trying out F# a bit recently, but I've almost exclusively used records and immutability. Now I'm trying mutable classes, however, and it's giving me some issues.

The biggest one so far is that it seems I can't assign to an element of an array that is a member of a class. For example, the following works as expected, replacing the 0th element with a 9:

```
let array = [| 0..5 |]
array.[0] <- 9
printfn "%A" array
```

However, this does not work as I would expect:

```
type MyClass () =
    member this.Array = [| 0..5 |]

let myClass = MyClass()
myClass.Array.[0] <- 9
printfn "%A" myClass.Array
```

The assignment seems to do nothing, but the compiler does not complain with even a warning. I assume there is something that prevents assignments to members of classes, including their submembers and elements, but I can't find any documentation or outside explanations of it.

Could someone help me understand what's going on here and give an example or two of how this is typically done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MyClass.Array`, the way you declared it, is a readonly property. You gave it a get accessor, and the body of that accessor consists of creating an array and returning it.

Spot the problem yet? It's a new array every time you call `MyClass.Array`. The first array does get mutated just fine, but then you just throw it away and request a new array from the class.

If you want to "store" an array "inside" the class, you need to give it a name, and then make your property accessor refer to that name. That way, the property accessor will return the same array every time:

```
type MyClass() =
    let theArray = [|0..5|]
    member this.Array = theArray
```

(incidentally, this very gotcha is one of the reasons to avoid mutable data)

Answer (score 1):

This is probably because the declaration you have defines this.Array as a read-only property. As mentioned in another answer, the code you have returns a new array for each call.

An auto property works and is a little more concise:

```
type MyClass () =
    member val Array = [| 0..5 |] with get,set


let myClass = MyClass()
myClass.Array.[0] <- 9
printfn "%A" myClass.Array // [|9; 1; 2; 3; 4; 5|]
```